# Usage of trap command in shell

Tags: bash, shell, signals

I am trying to trap the exit code "0" here. Whenever the exit code 0 is being trapped, check function is being called within trap, where I am trying to restart HW using command `hascli -rn /`, but this command execution is being skipped every time.

```
#!/bin/bash
source $TCE_COMMON
source commonFunctions.sh
trap "
     check
     " 0
checkRGservices
function check
{
 hascli -rn /
 %SLEEP 300
 %NODE none
 #!/bin/bash
 source $TCE_COMMON
 source commonFunctions.sh
 checkForCoreFiles
}
```

Can any one help me to get out of this.

Thanks in advance,
Mahi.

Comment: try "trap check EXIT" instead of your multi line construct

Comment: Why are you using that multi-line string? What's wrong with `trap check 0`?

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for the suggestion.I have tried this trap check 0 but it is of no use... It is displaying in the logs as "check: command not found"... Your advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi bobah, I have tried "trap check EXIT" also,the result is same.Please suggest me any optimal check for this.

Comment: Is checkRGservices exiting?  If so, the trap is being executed before the check function is defined.

Answer (score 2):

As *William* already assumed:

In contrast to languages as C or Java where a compiler scans the whole program before it starts, the shell is interpreted in a top-down manner. So to be able to use your function *check()* you have to define it prior to that. The error message `check: command not found` is a strong indicator for this kind of problem. Solution: Move the function definition of *check()* to above the *trap* command.

One note to the *trap* command in general: As *bobah* stated, use keywords (here: `EXIT`) instead of numbers (here: `0`) within the *trap* command. It makes your code more readable and in addition more portable, since not all *NIX Variants use the same numbers (although '0' is a special case here).

Comment: #!/bin/bash
source $TCE_COMMON
source commonFunctions.sh
checkRGservices
function check
{
 hascli -rn /
 %SLEEP 300
 %NODE none
 #!/bin/bash
 source $TCE_COMMON
 source commonFunctions.sh
 checkForCoreFiles
}
trap check EXIT.....

Comment: I have modified as above but hascli -rn / is being skipped every time,i run this script.... Please sugget me any solution.

Comment: unlikely that a command is skipped. Maybe you want to do something different. Note that the trap command causes the function to be called when your script terminates. Could it be that you meant something different - maybe checking the returncode of a command?

Comment: I am checking the return value of a command,where as I am trying to trap the same return value of the command...